# How to resolve "not Authorized 401" when accessing Geth using web3 package?

Tags: python, web3py, go-ethereum

I have this code in Python

```
from web3 import Web3
from lxml import html
import requests
import random
from colorama import Fore, Style
from hdwallet import HDWallet
from hdwallet.symbols import ETH as SYMBOL


z=0
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("http://localhost:8551", request_kwargs={'timeout': 60}))
f = open("ethkey.txt", "r")
password = "any"
while True:
    Linereader = f.readline(-1)
    Linereader = Linereader[:64]
    w3.geth.personal.import_raw_key(Linereader,password)
    z=z+1
    print("OK")
    continue
f.close()
```

This program gives:

> server refused to connect (not Authorized 401)

Can you please help?

I tried to enable personal from Geth, same problem persists.

I'm trying to import a private keys file into Geth using Web3 as the list is long.

Answer (score 0):

it's something related to initializing Geth with option like --rpc or --rpcapi for newer release of geth --rpcpredicatepersonal

so  it would be

geth --rpcpredicatepersonal

if it doesn't help there might be an authorization script for the configuration of geth you might want to read

Answer (score -1):

it's this line that gives the problem of 401

```
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("http://localhost:8551", request_kwargs={'timeout': 60}))
```

so I think there might be an argument of authorization

https://docs.web3js.org/guides/web3_providers_guide/

or try to use web sockets or IPC with proper geth initialization

https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/providers.html#web3.providers.rpc.HTTPProvider

[What is the of use Web3.providers.HttpProvider("")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49291445/what-is-the-of-use-web3-providers-httpprovider)

[What is the of use Web3.providers.HttpProvider("")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49291445/what-is-the-of-use-web3-providers-httpprovider)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67336484/python-web3-connect-to-ankr-binance-smart-chain-api-through-user-and-password#:~:text=You%20should%20save%20the%20headers%20on%20a%20Session,w3%20%3D%20Web3%20%28Web3.HTTPProvider%20%28%27https%3A%2F%2Fapis.ankr.com%2FXXXX%2FYYYY%2Fbinance%2Ffull%2Fmain%27%2C%20session%3Ds%29%29%20w3.isConnected%20%28%29](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67336484/python-web3-connect-to-ankr-binance-smart-chain-api-through-user-and-password#:%7E:text=You%20should%20save%20the%20headers%20on%20a%20Session,w3%20%3D%20Web3%20%28Web3.HTTPProvider%20%28%27https%3A%2F%2Fapis.ankr.com%2FXXXX%2FYYYY%2Fbinance%2Ffull%2Fmain%27%2C%20session%3Ds%29%29%20w3.isConnected%20%28%29)

in reference to web3 documentation there seems no authorizing but to use the provider http:// link like
[root:pass@http://bla:8551/](https://root:pass@http://localhost:8551/)